# How to get a dull and shadowed mesh with rgl?

Tags: r, opengl, 3d, mesh, rgl

Below are two meshes of the Barth sextic. The first one is obtained with the R package **rgl**. It is rather shiny and it has almost no shadow. The second one is obtained with the Haskell package **OpenGL**. It is dull and shadowed.

[image: Barth sextic - rgl]

[image: Barth sextic - haskell]

I'd like to know how to obtain a rendering similar to the Haskell one with **rgl**? As far as I know, both libraries are wrapper of **openGL**, so that should be possible.

```r
# isosurface f=0
phi <- (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
f <- function(x, y, z){
  4 * (phi^2*x^2 - y^2) * (phi^2*y^2 - z^2) * (phi^2*z^2 - x^2) - 
    (1 + 2*phi) * (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)^2
}
# make the isosurface
nx <- 220L; ny <- 220L; nz <- 220L
x <- seq(-1.8, 1.8, length.out = nx) 
y <- seq(-1.8, 1.8, length.out = ny)
z <- seq(-1.8, 1.8, length.out = nz) 
Grid <- expand.grid(X = x, Y = y, Z = z)
voxel <- array(with(Grid, f(X, Y, Z)), dim = c(nx, ny, nz))
mask  <- array(with(Grid, X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 > 3), dim = c(nx, ny, nz))
voxel[mask] <- -1000
library(rmarchingcubes)
cont <- contour3d(voxel, level = 0, x = x, y = y, z = z)
# plot
library(rgl)
mesh <- tmesh3d(
  vertices = t(cont[["vertices"]]),
  indices  = t(cont[["triangles"]]),
  normals  = cont[["normals"]],
  homogeneous = FALSE
)
#
open3d(windowRect = c(50, 50, 562, 562), zoom = 0.65)
shade3d(mesh, color = "#ff00ff")
```

The (unique) light in the Haskell scene is located at (-50, 100, 100) and has colors ambient=black, diffuse=white, specular=white.

Comment: Have you tried using different material parameters, for example, reducing the shininess (see [rgl.material](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgl/versions/0.110.2/topics/rgl.material))? I also seems that the position of the light source is different in the two images. The matlab version has the light placed directly in front of the object, while the Haskall version placed it bottom-left. About the terminology: From what I can see the Haskell version doesn't use shadows. It only uses dark colors for faces that are looking away from the light.

Comment: @BDL The shininess does not help. Indeed I think the solution deals with the lighting, but I don't know how to control the lights with **rgl**.

Comment: As far as I can remember, the light position is set with [`light3D`](https://rdrr.io/rforge/rgl/man/light.html), but I haven't used rgl in ages.

Comment: @BDL Surely, but one has to disable the default lights too. I'll try if nobody replies.

Comment: @BDL I've found. You were right, these are not shadows, this is the specular color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get it. One has to clear the default lighting first, then add a light like the one in the Haskell scene. I also set the specular color of the mesh to black.

```r
open3d(windowRect = c(50, 50, 562, 562), zoom = 0.65)
clear3d(type = "lights")
light3d(x = -50, y = 100, z = 100, ambient = "black")
shade3d(mesh, color = "#ff00ff", specular = "black")
```

[image]